# Installing gcc and gdb via pacman Msys

Tags: c++, gdb, msys2

I was installing gcc and gdb in my windows 64bit env but I face a network issue, then when I  tried to run "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb" or "pacman -Syu" it shows :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTNVd.png)

Any solutions?

I tried  removing /var/lib/pacman/db.lck using comand " pacman -R " but it did not work!

Comment: Did you try `rm -f /var/lib/pacman/db.lck` to delete the file? By remove they mean delete the file not use the package manager to remove a package.

Comment: I removed the VS code and gcc tags because they're totally unrelated to the question, but left the C++ and gdb tags because they may make this easier to find. That said the same problem could happen with any tool and language.

Comment: Stackoverflow usage note: there are almost no good reasons to include an image of text, particularly code and error messages, in a question or answer. Images exclude too many people from participating.

Answer (score 0):

By telling you to remove a lock file `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck` they want you to delete the file:

Type the following command in the mingw64 terminal to delete the file:

```
rm -f /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
```

They do not mean use the remove option of the package manager. The lock file is not a package. Instead its a file that pacman creates to make sure that you don't attempt multiple simultaneous installs which could corrupt the system packages.